# Stop duplicate requests before sending one in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I'm using **Angular 8**.

I have an analytics component which hit 10 endpoints to receive the analytics,
User can change the date or filter params and request for analysis again.

The issue is that, user can change the params when earlier analytics are being fetched, which creates another new request and thus returns values for twice.

I want to cancel the previous requests, if the new request is same.

**How can this be achieved in the Angular?**

Comment: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap

Comment: `if (currentRequest == prevRequest) return`

Comment: can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

If the user, is not allowed to change params while receiving the old request, you just need to disable the component elements by your promise, and enabel them after the success callback.

If not, you can just use the RxJS functions like : switchMap